# How to configure EKS ALB with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm having a hard time getting EKS to expose an IP address to the public internet. Do I need to set up the ALB myself or do you get that for free as part of the EKS cluster? If I have to do it myself, do I need to define it in the terraform template file or in the kubernetes object yaml?

Here's my EKS cluster defined in Terraform along with what I think are the required permissions.

```golang
// eks.tf

resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_cluster_role" {
  name = "${local.env_name}-eks-cluster-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "eks.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks-AmazonEKSVPCResourceController" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSVPCResourceController"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.name
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "eks_key" {
  description             = "EKS KMS Key"
  deletion_window_in_days = 7
  enable_key_rotation     = true

  tags = {
    Environment = local.env_name
    Service     = "EKS"
  }
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "eks_key_alias" {
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.eks_key.id
  name          = "alias/eks-kms-key-${local.env_name}"
}

resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
  name                      = "${local.env_name}-eks-cluster"
  role_arn                  = aws_iam_role.eks_cluster_role.arn
  enabled_cluster_log_types = ["api", "audit", "authenticator", "controllerManager", "scheduler"]

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.private_a.id, aws_subnet.private_b.id]
  }

  encryption_config {
    resources = ["secrets"]

    provider {
      key_arn = aws_kms_key.eks_key.arn
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = local.env_name
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_node_group_role" {
  name = "${local.env_name}-eks-node-group"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks-node-group-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_node_group_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks-node-group-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_node_group_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks-node-group-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_node_group_role.name
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks_node_group" {
  instance_types  = var.node_group_instance_types
  node_group_name = "${local.env_name}-eks-node-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_node_group_role.arn
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  subnet_ids      = [aws_subnet.private_a.id, aws_subnet.private_b.id]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 1
    max_size     = 1
    min_size     = 1
  }

  // Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Node Group handling.
  // Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EC2 Instances and Elastic Network Interfaces.
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.eks-node-group-AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
  ]
```

And here's my kubernetes object yaml:

```yaml
# hello-kubernetes.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hello-kubernetes
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-kubernetes
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-kubernetes
        image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: hello-kubernetes
    servicePort: 80
```

I've run `terraform apply` and the cluster is up and running. I've installed `eksctl` and `kubectl` and run `kubectl apply -f hello-kubernetes.yaml`. The pods, service, and ingress appear to be running fine.

```sh
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hello-kubernetes-6cb7cd595b-25bd9   1/1     Running            0          6h13m
hello-kubernetes-6cb7cd595b-lccdj   1/1     Running            0          6h13m
hello-kubernetes-6cb7cd595b-snwvr   1/1     Running            0          6h13m

$ kubectl get services
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
hello-kubernetes   LoadBalancer   172.20.102.37   <pending>     80:32086/TCP   6h15m

$ kubectl get ingresses
NAME            CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
hello-ingress   <none>   *                 80      3h45m
```

What am I missing and which file does it belong in?

Comment: Did you try the solutions provided in the answer section?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/latest/) by following the [installation instructions](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/latest/deploy/installation/); first you need to create IAM Role and permissions, this can be done with Terraform; then you need to apply Kubernetes Yaml for installing the controller into your cluster, this can be done with Helm or Kubectl.

You also need to be aware of the [subnet tagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html) that is needed for e.g. creating a public or private facing load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way to go is to put an ALB and redirect traffic to the EKS cluster, managing it with the ALB Ingress Controller. This ingress controller will act as the communication between the cluster and your ALB, here is the AWS documentation that is pretty straight foward

[EKS w/ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html)

Other solution could be using an NGINX ingress controller with an NLB if the ALB doesn't suits your applications needs, as described in the following article

[NGINX w/NLB](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/)

Comment: where do you define the ALB and the Ingress Controller? Does the ALB go in the terraform file and the Ingress Controller go in the kubernetes yaml? How do you wire them together?

Comment: As Jonas answered, follow the instructions detailed in the documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html  Then when you define your k8s ingress manifest, you use the annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb`. Here is a full example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html

Comment: I understand that there is no wiring between Terraform and the Ingress controller, you have to do this manually after the EKS was provisioned, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me too that after all the setup, I was not able to see the ingress address. The best way to debug this issue is to check the logs for the ingress controller. You can do this by:

Get the Ingress controller po name by using: kubectl get po -n kube-system
Check logs for the po using: kubectl logs <po_name> -n kube-system
This will point you to the exact issue as to why you are not seeing the address.

If you do not find any po running by the name ingress, then u will have to create ingress controller first.

Comment: Thanks, I do not see an ingress pod in the kube-system namespace. Do I create it in Terraform by adding it to the tf file or do I create it in Kubernetes by adding it to the yaml file?

Comment: I do see these four pods in the namespace, if that helps: aws-node-4jp4q, coredns, c79dcb98c-96npq, coredns-c79dcb98c-rqkxx, and kube-proxy-9zdcw.

Comment: You need to add it in using the yaml files. Follow the link: https://medium.com/cloudzone/aws-alb-ingress-controller-guide-ec16233f5903